# How to change the border height of the button?

Tags: android, xml

I need to change border height of the button. Is that possible?

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
<item  android:bottom="-10dp" android:left="-10dp" android:top="1dp">
  <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#323232" />
  </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

In this xml it is mentioned `android:width="1dp"`. Is there any way to give height of the border?

Comment: share your button image that you want

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming what you are looking for is to increase the stroke width. The border that you currently see around the button is the stroke that you set using the following line:

```
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#323232" />
```

To increase the border height is as simple as increasing the `android:width` here. For example:

```
<stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#323232" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for adjusting border. Which is depend on **android:width**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
<item  android:bottom="-10dp" android:left="-10dp" android:top="1dp">
  <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#323232" />
  </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The parameter **android:width="5dp"** in **stroke** is used for specify how much border width. If you want in px then use just **android:width="5px"**.